# Vue3 reactivity weird behavior

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, vuejs3

I am learning vue3 reactivity system and cannot figure out the following strange behavior. Here's my code.

```
setup(props) {
    let weekDay = props.weekDay;
    let taskState = reactive({
        [weekDay]: [[{
            description: '',
            status: '',
        }]],
    });
    function changeStatus(index, event) {
        let task = taskState[weekDay][index];  //works
        taskState[weekDay][index] = {
            ...task,
            status: event.target.value
        };
    }
    return {
      taskState,
      changeStatus
    }
}
```

updating the state status reactively looks like  works, but if i change the  function like below, this would not work. Why is it happening? are object **task** and **taskState[weekDay][index]** not
same ?

```
    function changeStatus(index, event) {
        let task = taskState[weekDay][index]; //not works
        task = { 
            ...task,                        
            status: event.target.value   
        }; 
    }
```

Comment: I see that you're nesting another array `[[{ description: '', status: '', }]]`  I think it should be `[{ description: '', status: '', }]`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim - `taskState[weekDay][index]` would be an Object, in both cases, not an Array

Comment: it would give something like `[{ description: '', status: '', }]`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim it doesn't matter, the question is why do I need to explicitly update the task State object to trigger reactivity and not another object like a task that is the same with reference?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  **task** object is not a reactive, because we change the value using an assignment to a regular object, and the object **task** no longer has a  reactive parent such as **taskState**, so there is no setter attached to it and a simple value is returned, instead of a reactive proxy

```
function changeStatus(index, event) {
    let task = taskState[weekDay][index]; //not works
    task = { 
        ...task,                        
        status: event.target.value   
    }; 
}
```

if we want to make it work we should use like this:

```
 function changeStatus(index, event) {
        let task = taskState[weekDay]; //works
        task[index] = { 
            ...task[index],                        
            status: event.target.value   
        }; 
    }
```

in that case **task[index]** will be reactive and the setter will be triggered in the **taskState[weekDay]** object